# Print the text of the pre tag

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I'm relatively new to python and selenium. I want to print the text in the pre tag of the given snippet using python selenium.

```
<body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
 " sample text i want to get 
   print this using python selenium
 "
</pre></body>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to find the required tag and get the element's text.

Since this is only `pre` tag on the page, we can use xpath like this:

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//pre").text)
```

Comment: hi still i am getting the same error, no xpath found.

Comment: Then that means that you have invalid XPath. Fix it.